# moving a window widget

Tags: gtk

I have two windows, one main window which lies behind second window.

How can i move the second window along with main window, when ever the main window

moves. And second window is ordinary window, it will have reference to main window.

Regards,
iSight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can connect to the [configure-event](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-configure-event) of your first window and change position of the second window accordingly to x and y coordinates which are coming via [GdkEvent](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gdk/stable/gdk-Event-Structures.html) structure. Below is a small example:

```
void configure_callback(GtkWindow *window, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data)
{
    int x = event->configure.x;
    int y = event->configure.y;
    gtk_widget_set_uposition(GTK_WIDGET(data), x+220, y);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget *window0 = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window0), "Window 0");
    gtk_widget_set_uposition(window0, 20, 40);

    GtkWidget *window1 = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window1), "Window 1");
    gtk_widget_set_uposition(window1, 240, 40);

    g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window0), "destroy",
            G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), G_OBJECT(window0));
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window0), "configure-event",
            G_CALLBACK(configure_callback), window1);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window0);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window1);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

once you move "window 0", "window 1" should change its position accordingly.

hope this helps, regards

Comment: I have used this but, the window1 is not moving along with window0 instantly. Instead, moves only after mouse has released window0. How can i obtained moving two window instantly while other moves.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this question when I tried to answer this one: [How do you save a gui to file in GtkD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640739/how-do-you-save-a-gui-to-file-in-gtkd)

The demo code is modified to answer your question, and here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from gi.repository import Gtk
import json
import os


class Demo():

    def __init__(self):
        self.conf_name = 'demo.json'
        self.read_config()
        self.init_widgets()
        self.init_window_position()

    def init_widgets(self):
        self.window = Gtk.Window()
        self.window.set_title('window 1')
        self.window.connect('check-resize', self.on_window_check_resize)
        self.window.connect('configure-event',
                self.on_window_configure_event)
        self.window.connect('destroy', self.on_app_exit)

        label = Gtk.Label('hello, world')
        self.window.add(label)

        self.window2 = Gtk.Window()
        self.window2.set_title('window 2')
        self.window2.connect('configure-event',
                self.on_window2_configure_event)

    def init_window_position(self):
        # restore window size and position.
        # we need to read these values from app configuration.
        self.window.move(self.conf['window_x'], self.conf['window_y'])
        self.window2.move(self.conf['window_x'] + self.conf['pos_diff_x'], 
                self.conf['window_y'] + self.conf['pos_diff_y'])
        self.window.set_default_size(self.conf['window_width'],
                self.conf['window_height'])

    def read_config(self):
        if os.path.isfile(self.conf_name):
            with open(self.conf_name) as fh:
                self.conf = json.loads(fh.read())
        else:
        # default configuration.
            self.conf = {
                    'window_x': 100,
                    'window_y': 100,
                    'window_width': 320,
                    'window_height': 240,
                    # distance between window1 and window2 in x dimention.
                    'pos_diff_x': 120, 
                    # distance between window1 and window2 in y dimention.
                    'pos_diff_y': 120,
                    }

    def write_config(self):
        with open(self.conf_name, 'w') as fh:
            fh.write(json.dumps(self.conf))

    def run(self):
        self.window.show_all()
        self.window2.show_all()
        Gtk.main()

    def on_app_exit(self, widget):
        # new setting is dumped when app exits.
        self.write_config()
        Gtk.main_quit()

    def on_window_check_resize(self, window):
        print('check resize')
        width, height = self.window.get_size()
        print('size: ', width, height)
        self.conf['window_width'] = width
        self.conf['window_height'] = height

    def on_window_configure_event(self, window, event):
        print('configure event')
        x, y = self.window.get_position()
        print('position:', x, y)
        self.conf['window_x'] = x
        self.conf['window_y'] = y

        # now move window2.
        self.window2.move(x + self.conf['pos_diff_x'],
                y + self.conf['pos_diff_y'])

    def on_window2_configure_event(self, window, event):
        '''
        If window2 is moved by user, pos_diff_x and pos_diff_y need to be
        recalculated.
        '''
        print('window2 configure event')
        x2, y2 = self.window2.get_position()
        print('position: ', x2, y2)
        self.conf['pos_diff_x'] = x2 - self.conf['window_x']
        self.conf['pos_diff_y'] = y2 - self.conf['window_y']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo = Demo()
    demo.run()
```

And a screenshot:

[image]